# Unexpected token in JSON at positon 0

Tags: javascript, php, json

I always get Unexpected token in JSON at positon 0 in my code

the echo json will be

```
["pen","pencil","apple","cat","dog"]
```

and the console will get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 0

php code :

```
    <?php

        include 'Connect_2.php';
        header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
        $Store_int =$_GET['num'];

        #execute sql function and return result
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `store` WHERE `Place_int` = ".$Store_int;

        mysqli_select_db($link,"web");
        $link -> set_charset("utf8");
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

        $arr = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
            $p =(string) $row -> Name;
            $arr[]=$p;
        }
        //print_r($arr);
        $jsonArr = json_encode($arr,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

        echo ($jsonArr);
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
```

.js code

```
function getArr(store_int){
var jsArray = new Array();
$.ajax({
    url: "fromSQL_store.php",
    data: {
        num: store_int
    },
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        jsArray = JSON.parse(data);
        //jsArray = data;
    },error: function(data,XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
//alert(jsArray.length);
console.log(jsArray[0]);
return jsArray;
```

}

if I use `jsArray = data ;`the `console(jsArray[0])` will show undefined.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: @Enstage thanks , i will modify the problem after solving

Comment: @Zi-yanTseng did you checked my answer . i hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already JSON. Don't call `jsArray = JSON.parse(data);` Instead, just treat `data` like a JSON object.

Instead of `console(jsArray[0])` call `console(jsArray)` The `data` object doesn't seem to be an array.

**Also**, it looks like you're console.log is being called right after you send the ajax request, which isn't giving you any time to receive the response to populate the object, so it's going to be empty. Put the console.log in the success callback of the ajax request.

`JSON.parse()` throws this error when it's parsing something that's already JSON which is really annoying since it sure would be nice if it instead just returned the original JSON back to you or at least threw a more precise error like "Error: This is already JSON."

Comment: hello , but i wll get undefined at jsArray[0]

Comment: Then is `data` an array or just JSON? What happens if you try just `console(jsArray)` ?

Comment: it will be `[]` the empty array ?

Comment: That's probably because of a timing issue, your ajax call hasn't had time to come back and populate `data`. Put the console.log in the success callback of the ajax.

Comment: thanks, you're right, but how can i get the value to outside?

Comment: Such is the nature of asynchronous programming. Here's a decent explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004822/get-variable-from-callback-function

Comment: @Zi-yanTseng if this was the correct answer, would you please accept it to help others find it as a solution?

Comment: hello,my router is breaken because of the high temperature.. I have to wait 5~10 minutes to connect the Net. (I'm using my 4g net by my phone to answer)

Comment: hi , the ISP finally return me the NET. I put `console.log(jsArray)` into `success` , and it can show the right answer.  However , I can't put `return` into `success` . it won't work

Comment: and you'r right , i don't need to `JSON.parse()` . because php pass the json format as string , and using array variable in javascript will parse to proper type automatically

Answer (score 0):

May be your response header `Content-Type` is `text/html` instead of `application/json`.

Hence, If the response header is `text/html` you need to parse the text into JSON Object but if the response header is `application/json` then it is already parsed into `JSON Object`.

The solution is to set correct `Content-Type` header.

**If response header (Content-Type) is text/html :**

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(responseData);
```

**If response header (Content-Type) is application/json :**

```
var jsonObj = responseData;
```

Comment: hi , in the php code , 3rd line has declared application/json.

Comment: But i think this content header in php file is just give information about type of returned data. i am not sure about that

Comment: Then your `data` response is already parsed, no need to parse it again.

Comment: ok thanks,  i can get the value from php successfully , however , i can't return the value from `getArr` function